# How to select inner bone first?

Tags: bones

I would like to be able to select inner bone first just by clicking on it rather than clicking on the outer bone then re clicking on the inner bone. That would speed up my work tremendously. How can I do that? There is an option which I need to "check" to enable this kind of selecting?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the circle of the head of the inner bone.

[image]